# Adding Headers to Fetch POST request in Desktop Add-in event-activation

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Add-in for Outlook Desktop and want to call my service during the `OnNewMessageCompose` event.

I'm using fetch like this. I'm posting to the my service with a token and a body

```
const result = await fetch('https://myservice.com/endpoint', {
mode: 'cors',
method: 'POST',
headers: {
    'Content-Type' : 'applications/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer : token'
},
body: JSON.stringify(body)
});
```

When the add-in runs within the web version of Outlook, it's fine. When run in the Desktop. it fails. A similar issue was reported regarding Excel Custom functions and the solution was to use the Sharedruntime. That does not appear to be available in Outlook. If I take out the headers it's fine, but ideally I need those to authorize against the service. Is there a way to pass custom headers via a POST in the Desktop version of an add-in?

Answer (score 0):

Desktop Outlook does not support SharedRuntime, so that workaround won't work. We have documented the lack of Full CORS support online. Search for **Full CORS** on this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch

As a workaround for now, ensure that your add-in and your service are on the same origin to eliminate the need for CORS.

We are currently working to support Full CORS. Unfortunately, we don't have any timelines to share.